# Monitor file for an append and perform some action after the append is done

Tags: python, watchdog, file-monitoring

wI've created 2 separate scripts to crawl, scrape and save the results to a csv file and upload the file to dropbox which i run manually. Now what i want is to monitor the csv file while performing the append operation and then upload the file once the append operation is over. Can anyone throw me some idea or examples to do this as i'm new to this. I saw a package named **watchdog** but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Comment: Why do you want to monitor a file, that you create and append to yourself?

Comment: The crawler crawls through sites matching a fixed regex, scrapes data and then stores the scraped data in a csv file. So, for that a  csv file is created and data is written to it, everytime the scraper scrapes the content of the url. I'd like to monitor the status of the csv file whether data is being currently written or not and if not i'd like to upload the file to dropbox.

Answer (score 4):

`watchdog` is really simple to use. I've written sample code here, and it will monitor the change on your `*.csv` file. Set your path before using it... a simple `./` also works:

```
import time

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class ChangeHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.csv"] # Only handle csv files

    def __init__(self):
        super(ChangeHandler, self).__init__()

    def process(self, event):
        '''
        event.event_type: The type of the event as a string.
        event.src_path: Source path of the file system object
                that triggered this event
        event.is_directory: True if event was emitted for
                a directory; False otherwise.
        '''
        print event.event_type
        print event.src_path
        print event.is_directory
        # DO UPLOAD HERE

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_deleted(self, event):
        '''
        file is deleted, maybe do some other operations?
        '''
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(ChangeHandler(), path='your_csv_folder_path_here',
                      recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explore into [Pynotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki). Though I have not used it personally.